# Не загружается образ img MSDOS2

Tags: dos

Я загрузил из интернета образ флоппи 360 Килобайт MSDOS 2.11. Загружаю этот образ dos2.img в программе VirtualBox все работает. Далее моя последовательность действий. Для теста я решил сделать свой образ img. Что я делаю. Извлекаю загрузочный сектор из dos2.img - программа проверенная, ошибки быть не может, после извлечения этой программой заглядываю в файл бут сектора msboot.bin и последние два байта как и должно быть 0xAA55.

Далее из образа dos2.img копирую себе в папку MSDOS2_SYS файлы IBMBIO.COM, IBMDOS.COM, COMMAND.COM - далее пытаюсь собрать свой образ MSDOS 2.11 таким образом. Есть у меня bat файл для сборки образа. Сначала я копирую бут сектор в образ так:

```
echo Adding bootsector to disk image...
%MYPATH%\dd.exe count=2 seek=0 bs=512 if=%MYPATH%\msboot.bin of=%MYPATH%\msdos2.img
```

Далее на мой образ записываю системные файлы так

```
echo Mounting disk image...
%MYPATH%\imdisk.exe -a -f %MYPATH%\msdos2.img -s 360K -m B:

echo Copying kernel and applications to disk image...

copy %MYPATH%\MSDOS2_SYS\IBMBIO.COM b:\
copy %MYPATH%\MSDOS2_SYS\IBMDOS.COM b:\
copy %MYPATH%\MSDOS2_SYS\COMMAND.COM b:\

echo Dismounting disk image...
%MYPATH%\imdisk.exe -D -m B:
```

Мой готовый образ загружаю в VirtualBox виснет на загрузке, выдает пару строк текста что началась загрузка MSDOS 2.11 потом виснет. Причем я делаю свой образ из оригинальных файлов. В чем может быть проблема? Может там в этой версии MSDOS с другой позиции идет загрузка IBMBIO.SYS и других файлов? Пробовал аналогичный метод на MSDOS6.22 все работает. Что тут может быть?

Comment: ЕМНИП MS-DOS 2.11 требует, чтобы файлы IBMBIO.COM, IBMDOS.COM, COMMAND.COM были записаны на носитель самыми первыми (первые три записи в корневом каталоге - даже затесавшаяся меж ними метка диска валит загрузку), без фрагментации, и именно в таком порядке. Проверь в хексах сектор корневого каталога и цепочки ФАТ для этих файлов.

Comment: Спасибо, какая есть программа проверить?

Comment: Да любой хекс-вьювер.

Comment: Я знаю что в MS-DOS2.11 эти три файла должны быть первыми в корневой директории. Как и MS-DOS 6.22, но для MS-DOS 6.22 этот мой способ работает, для MS-DOS 2.11 нет. В чем дело не пойму.

Comment: Смотрел heх viewer корневой каталог первые два файла в оригинальном img IBMBIO.COM, IBMDOS.COM лежит в начале корневого каталога и COMMAND.COM лежит посреди других файлов. В моем img тоже IBMBIO.COM, IBMDOS.COM лежит в начале корневого каталога и и COMMAND.COM лежит посреди других файлов (я скопировал все файлы с ориг. img на мой img). В чем дело не пойму. Пользуюсь imdisk.

Comment: А первые два файла случайно не фоагментированы? Проверь, что цепь FAT без прыжков.

Comment: Я посмотрю. Но почему файлы могут быть фрагментированы? Когда я делаю IMG для MSDOS622 imdisk не фрагментирует и MSDOS622 IMG отлично грузиться. А когда я делаю IMG для MSDOS2 imdisk почему то может фрагментировать файлы?

Comment: Вот чисто теоретически - Вы же пытаетесь, как я понимаю, воспроизвести загрузочную дискету из имеющихся файлов и бут-сектора, верно? ну так что мешает сравнить побайтно два образа (взяв куски с бутом, таблицами ФАТ, корневым каталогом и системными файлами) и найти разницу (без учёта разницы в неиспользуемых "хвостах" последнего кластера файла)?

Comment: Да как вы говорите я пытаюсь воспроизвести загрузочную дискету. Получилось. Первые три байта FAT в оригинальном IMG 0xfd 0xff 0xff а первые три байта в моем IMG 0x00 0x00 0x00, я отрыл мой IMG на С++, заменил первые три байта FAT в моем IMG, и все заработало. Дело в том что 0xfd в FAT в оригинальном IMG обозначает что это floppy 360K, видимо это играет роль при загрузке системы. Значит вывод, что программа imdisk которой я пользуюсь для создания IMG немного не так создает IMG как надо. Вы навели меня на интересные мысли Akina! Огоромное спасибо!